# UserForm resize code not quite working

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to write some code to handle resizing & moving controls when the form is resized.

My approach is to create a Dictionary object for each Control dimension that needs to be anchored (i.e. top/left/width/height) with the key being the control name and anchor dimension (e.g. lstAccounts_Height) and to add these to a form-level Collection. On the form `Resize` event the Collection is iterated through, and each Control adjusted as necessary.

The routine to add controls:

```
Private Sub AddFormResizeControl(ControlName As String, _
                                 Dimension As String)

Dim strKey                      As String
Dim sngValue                    As Single
Dim dictCtrl                    As Dictionary

    strKey = ControlName & "_" & Dimension

    Select Case Dimension
        Case "Left": sngValue = Controls(ControlName).Left
        Case "Top": sngValue = Controls(ControlName).Top
        Case "Width": sngValue = Controls(ControlName).Width
        Case "Height": sngValue = Controls(ControlName).Height
    End Select

    Set dictCtrl = New Dictionary
    dictCtrl.Add strKey, sngValue

    If colResizeControls Is Nothing Then _
        Set colResizeControls = New Collection
    colResizeControls.Add dictCtrl, strKey

End Sub
```

And adding the controls in the `Initialize` event:

```
AddFormResizeControl "lst_AccountSelection", "Width"
AddFormResizeControl "lst_AccountSelection", "Height"
AddFormResizeControl "cmd_Cancel", "Left"
AddFormResizeControl "cmd_Cancel", "Top"
AddFormResizeControl "cmd_Confirm", "Left"
AddFormResizeControl "cmd_Confirm", "Top"
```

And the `Resize` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Resize()

Dim sngHeightAdjust             As Single
Dim sngWidthAdjust              As Single

Dim dict                        As Dictionary
Dim strCtrl                     As String

Dim ctrl                        As Control
Dim strDimension                As String

    If Me.Width < sngFormMinimumWidth Then Me.Width = sngFormMinimumWidth
    If Me.Height < sngFormMinimumHeight Then Me.Height = sngFormMinimumHeight

    sngHeightAdjust = (Me.Height - 4.5) - sngFormMinimumHeight
    sngWidthAdjust = (Me.Width - 4.5) - sngFormMinimumWidth

    If Not colResizeControls Is Nothing Then
        For Each dict In colResizeControls
            strCtrl = dict.Keys(0)
            Set ctrl = Controls(Left(strCtrl, InStrRev(strCtrl, "_") - 1))
            If Right(strCtrl, 5) = "_Left" Then
                ctrl.Left = dict.Item(strCtrl) + sngWidthAdjust
            ElseIf Right(strCtrl, 4) = "_Top" Then
                ctrl.Top = dict.Item(strCtrl) + sngHeightAdjust
            ElseIf Right(strCtrl, 6) = "_Width" Then
                ctrl.Width = dict.Item(strCtrl) + sngWidthAdjust
            ElseIf Right(strCtrl, 7) = "_Height" Then
                ctrl.Height = dict.Item(strCtrl) + sngHeightAdjust
            End If
        Next dict
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem I am facing is that there is a small "jump" on the first move event, and consequently the runtime controls are not quite aligned as they at design-time. I have tried to counter this effect by changing the returned height and width for the form by 4.5, which does help.

The `sngFormMinimumHeight` and `sngFormMinimumWidth` are set as the starting width/height or the form in the `Initialize` event, and I am using [Chip Pearson's code](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/formcontrol.aspx) to make the form resizeable.

I'm guessing that there are some kind of borders on the form which need to be adjusted for (hence the 4.5s helping the issue) - can anyone explain what values I need to adjust by?

**Resolution** Thanks to the link provided by BonCodigo, the issue is now resolved - I was referring to `Me.Height` and `Me.Width` when I should have been referring to `Me.InsideHeight` and `Me.InsideWidth`. I now do not need the adjustment of 4.5 and the "jump" is now gone

Comment: any possibility that you could show your form to us? Although you seem to resize the form, it doesn't seem to position the controls (if you have any) well and adjust...

Comment: The resizing/re-positioning occurs during the For Each loop - the relevant anchor dimension is increased/decreased by sngHeightAdjust or sngWidthAdjust

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to change both `Anchor` and `Dock` properties of the `controls` and they should  automatically resize with their `parent containers` (perhaps a panel).

- Following reference is in MS Access, you could adapt it though: http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/controls/components/form-resizer/index.html
- [Resizer class and application from AndyPope](http://www.andypope.info/vba/resizeform.htm).

Comment: Thanks, but this is Excel and the humble UserForm has no such properties

Comment: AndyPope's article is mainly for Excel. And most probably you will have to keep track of the `resizing ratio` in that case and apply it to the controls as well..

Comment: Apologies, I completely misread your answer. Andy Pope's approach is similar to mine, but I see he is using InsideHeight/InsideWidth, which I think may be what I'm after. I will do some testing now

Comment: =) voila that's what you were referring as *border* ;) +1 for the question.

Comment: I've just tested using InsideHeight & Width and it now works fine, many thanks for your help!

Comment: Glad you got it worked :D each time there's an interesting question you learn we learn and it helps community too. Let us know if everything is alright, after you test it overall.

Comment: I am trying to do something similiar, and tried both andypope and cpearson code which quite dont work for me. My problem is that the form I made is rather wide 966 and heigh 777 which works fine for most, but on some laptop they run 800*600 and there it is a problem, so did @CrazyHorse update your code and will your code work to resize 966 to screen resolution of 800?